# Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_bios, Win32_operatingsystem,?

Tags: powershell

```
$Button1.Add_Click({ $TextBox1.Text = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_bios).caption + (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_bios).caption})
```

Is there a way to convert above to an array or something similar? for example:

```
$Button1.Add_Click({ $TextBox1.Text = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_bios, Win32_operatingsystem, Win32_etc , etc,etc).caption
```

Comment: have you tried to build an array or a PSCustomObject in your code? you can have the button trigger a function with almost any code in it ...

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
$Button1.Add_Click({ 
  $TextBox1.Text = @(
    'Win32_bios', 'Win32_operatingsystem' |Get-CimInstance -ClassName {$_} -ComputerName .
  ).Caption -join [Environment]::NewLine
})
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I tried to add a linebreak for eachone, but i dont get it. Do you have any idea how to do it? :)